# Simple injector register per web request and with context

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

There is `RegisterPerWebRequest` and `RegisterWithContext` (this one is not originally shipped with simple injector, however it supplied on their [advanced-scenarios section](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ContextDependentExtensions&referringTitle=Advanced-scenarios)). Separately both approaches works fine but I need to combine them.

I figured out that in `RegisterPerWebRequest` used `new WebRequestLifestyle()` lifestyle (found it [there](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SimpleInjectorV2.3/SimpleInjector.Integration.Web/SimpleInjectorWebExtensions.cs)). So instead of using `Lifestyle.Transient` `RegisterWithContext` I supplied `new WebRequestLifestyle()` but it appears that `DependencyContext.ImplementationType` and `DependencyContext.ServiceType` are null.

What is wrong with that?

**Update 1.**

So I wanted to Register type per web request as does `RegisterPerWebRequest` but also to be able to provide instance creator with access to type where registered type is injected.

I modified (extracted lifestyle as a parameter) `RegisterWithContext` to be:

```
public static void RegisterWithContext<TService>(
    this Container container,
    Func<DependencyContext, TService> contextBasedFactory, Lifestyle lifestyle)
    where TService : class
{
    //original code

    container.Register<TService>(rootFactory, lifestyle);

    //original code
}
```

And for "per web request and with context" registration I expected to be able use:

```
container.RegisterWithContext<IUnitOfWork>(dependencyContext =>
{
      var implementationType = dependencyContext.ImplementationType;
      //do some stuff and return preconfigured UnitOfWork
}, new WebRequestLifestyle());
```

And as I already mentioned `dependencyContext.ImplementationType` is `NULL`

I am using SimpleInjector 2.3.0.0

Comment: Can you be more specific? In what way do you want to mix them? Can you give a code example of what you need? And which version of Simple Injector are you using?

Comment: Dear @Steven I have updated my question. Generally, I am trying to achieve is supplying different connection strings for some selected repositories in some special cases. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `RegisterWithContext` extension method explicitly registers the supplied delegate as `Transient`. This is done, because registering the type with any other lifestyle makes little sense.

The idea of a lifestyle such as the `WebRequestLifestyle` is to cache and reuse the same instance throughout the object graph (and possibly beyond that). This concept however, makes little sense when dealing with a context-based registration, simply because a context-based instance is expected to be different each time it gets injected. In other words, supplying each consumer with a unique instance conflicts with the concept of reusing the same instance.

Take for instance a look at the following object graph:

```
new HomeController(
    new Logger("HomeController"),
    new LoggingRepositoryDecorator<User>(
        new Logger("LoggingRepositoryDecorator<User>"),
        new SqlRepository<User>(
            new DbContext())),
    new LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<ShipOrder>(
        new Logger("LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<ShipOrder>"),
        new ShipOrderCommandHandler(
            new DbContext())));
```

In this object graph we create a `HomeController` with its dependencies. The `Logger` component is clearly a context-based component, since its initialized differently every time, based on its parent. This would be the registration for `Logger`:

```
container.RegisterWithContext<ILogger>(context =>
    new Logger(context.ImplementationType.Name));
```

But if we allowed the `ILogger` registration to be registered with the `WebRequestLifestyle`, the same instance should be applied every time, which might lead to the following object graph:

```
ILogger logger = new Logger(typeName: "HomeController");

new HomeController(
    logger,
    new LoggingRepositoryDecorator<User>(
        logger,
        new SqlRepository<User>(
            new DbContext())),
    new LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<ShipOrder>(
        logger,
        new ShipOrderCommandHandler(
            new DbContext())));
```

In this object graph the same `Logger("HomeController")` is injected, which is clearly not what we want. Furthermore, the behavior becomes very unpredictable, since it is the consumer that gets created first, that will determine the logger's `typeName` that gets reused throughout the graph. But nobody would expect that removing the `ILogger` from the `HomeController`'s constructor, would cause the logger of the `LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<ShipOrder>` to change.

That's why there is no `Lifestyle` argument in the `RegisterWithContext` extension method.

Comment: thank you for so descriptive answer, I got so deep understanding of some principles in Simple injector. And separate thank you for all your efforts and contribution to simple injector development.